# Python script prints results on HTML surface

Tags: python, html, web

I've written a very simple chatbot in Python.
It works like if you write something in, it does the Python-based calculations and gives back an answer. Because it checks your previous answers as well, the python script needs to run continuously.
I'd like to put the chatbot online, and:

1. Send the input from the HTML surface back to the server as the source for the raw_input()
2. Then send back the Python output to the frontend as an answer and as a newline on the chat in the browser in HTML.

My Python code is:

```
def conversation(question):
     answer = #... ... ...(doesnt matter right now)

     print "CHATBOT: " + answer
     next_question = raw_input("YOU: ")
     return next_question

#==========================
#INTRO & CALLING FUNTCTIONS
#==========================
print "Hi, my name is CHATBOT!"

#Starts with user input.
question = ""
question = raw_input("You: ")

#calling the conversation function
question = conversation(question)
```

The question is: how can I connect the Python script with my website? How can users interact with my script from a website as I do on my Terminal?

I'm pretty sure it's very easy, but I have no idea where to start...
THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

You need some kind of server. In your case, you could for example use WebSockets or HTTP.

For WebSockets, there are Python solutions like [Autobahn](http://autobahn.ws/). WebSocket remember state, that's good for what you want to do. That's probably what you should use.

For HTTP, a simple Python solution is [Bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/index.html).

```
from bottle import route, run, template
@route('/hello/<name>')
def index(name):
    return template('<b>Hello {{name}}</b>!', name=name)
run(host='localhost', port=8080)
```

But HTTP is *stateless*, so you don't remember the last connection. You'd need a way to remember the chat of *that particular user* by creating a cookie/session for each individual user.

Also, you'd still need to connect that to a web server like Nginx.

Answer (score 0):

Nice chatbot app!  The trick is to keep your *flow control* and your functions separate.

So I did two minor tweaks:

1. I took the flow control from `conversation` and but it in `main`
2. I changed the `print` statement in `conversation` to a `return` statement because you want to keep your printing to screen and logic functions seperate as well if you can :)

Other than that, off to a great start!w

```
def conversation(question):
 answer = #... ... ...(doesnt matter right now)
 return "CHATBOT: " + answer

def main():
    while True:
        next_question = raw_input("YOU: ")
        print(conversation(next_question))

#==========================
#INTRO & CALLING FUNTCTIONS
#==========================

print "Hi, my name is CHATBOT!"
main()
```